# MYSQL Search returning wrong and duplicate values

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a project at university and I seem to be encountering some issues when i'm trying to search to collect some results.

I am trying to display the results which give the StudentName, ModuleName, and DegreeID. When I do this, it appears to be duplicating the values and returning wrong results.

For example - Owen Barnes is only studying Computer Science, not Philosophy yet it is simply returning all values instead of the specified 3 it should. Further, Connor Borne is studying Philosophy yet it is suggesting he is studying every module including those in Computer Science.

I was hoping someone could help me. I'm using 2 tables (ModulesFormDegree & StudiesModules) which are used to link Modules to Degree (using 2 foreign keys) and Students with Modules (also using 2 foreign keys).

I've attached my problem below, if any more data is required please let me know.

[Inquiry & Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NxnR.png)
[Description of Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXE6h.png)

Query:

```
select StudentName, ModuleName, DegreeID 
from Student, Modules, Degree, StudiesModules, ModulesFormDegree 
where Student.StudentID=StudiesModules.StudentID and 
      Modules.ModuleID=ModulesFormDegree.ModID and 
      Degree.DegreeID=ModulesFormDegree.DegID
```

Comment: what is the query you have written?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your query.

Comment: Sorry, it seems to have duplicated my image. I will edit now to show.

Comment: can you add your query an tables as text rather than an image?
I suspect your problem could be solved by using ANSI join syntax

Comment: Hi @philcode101, please add your query as text instead of an image to make it easy for others to help you.

Comment: of course, sorry one second

Comment: I think you missed `StudiesModules.ModuleID = Modules.ModuleID`

Comment: Got it!! Thanks @JulioDanielReyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's diffcult to say for sure because you have not posted all your table definitions but your query is missing a condition in the where clause which is causing the Cartesian product and can be fixed as follows:

```
select  StudentName,
        ModuleName,
        DegreeID
from    Student,
        Modules,
        Degree,
        StudiesModules,
        ModulesFormDegree
where   Student.StudentID=StudiesModules.StudentID and
        Modules.ModuleID=ModulesFormDegree.ModID and
        Degree.DegreeID=ModulesFormDegree.DegID and
        StudiesModules.ModuleID = ModulesFormDegree.ModID
```

however, joining tables on conditions in the WHERE clause is fairly antiquated and superseded using ANSI joins as follows:

```
SELECT  StudentName,
        ModuleName,
        DegreeID
FROM    StudiesModules sm
        JOIN ModulesFormDegree md
            ON sm.ModuleID = md.ModID
        JOIN Degree d
            On d.DegreeID = md.DegID
        JOIN Modules m
            ON m.ModuleID = md.ModID
        JOIN Student s
            ON s.StudentID = sm.StudentID
```

Comment: Hi, the where clause is there on my query as you've written! It is worth noting I am only allowed to use the where query for some reason in my project.

Comment: I added the last condition. Your query above has three conditions, mine has four

Comment: Oh I see! Sorry for my confusion, im very new to sql (as you can probably tell!) I will re attempt this query once i'm home and let you know the results!